# zshで連想配列を使用したいのですが、うまくいきません。

Tags: macos, shellscript, zsh

macOSのzshでシェルススクリプトを書いているのですが、連想配列（declareコマンド）を使う時  `-A` オプションを使うというサンプルがインターネットには多く見られますが、実際に使用してみると、オプションが存在しないと言われます。

さらに、1〜9までのキーは参照されるのですが、0やアルファベットのキーは参照されず、一番最後の要素が参照されてしまいます。

以上を踏まえ、以下の２点が知りたいです。

1. `declare` の `-A` オプションはどのシェル (bashなど) で有効なオプションなのでしょうか？
2. 最後の要素が参照されるのはどうしてなのか

実際のソースは以下の通りです。

```
declare sample=(
    ['1']="100 100"
    ['2']="200 200"
    ['3']="300 300"
    ['4']="400 400"
    ['5']="500 500"
    ['6']="600 600"
    ['0']="00000 00000"
    ['A']="AAAAA AAAAA"
    ['B']="BBBBB BBBBB"
)

echo ${sample['1']}
echo ${sample['2']}
echo ${sample['3']}
echo ${sample['4']}
echo ${sample['5']}
echo ${sample['6']}
echo ${sample['0']}
echo ${sample['A']}
echo ${sample['B']}
```

実行結果

```
100 100
200 200
300 300
400 400
500 500
600 600
BBBBB BBBBB
BBBBB BBBBB
BBBBB BBBBB
```

Comment: お使いの zsh のバージョンを追記して下さい(`zsh --version` を実行するか、zsh 内で `echo ${ZSH_VERSION}` を実行する)。ちなみに、こちらの zsh は version 5.8 なのですが、`declare sample ...` を `declare -A sample ...` として、`echo ${sample['1']}` を `echo ${sample[1]}` とする(他も同様)と想定通りに動作します。

Answer (score 0):

Macのbashはバージョンが低いのでbrewから5系をダウンロードしてインストールし
`#!/usr/local/bin/bash` でシェルスクリプトを作る必要があります。
Macの3系の古いbashだと空白があると上手く動作しませんね。

もしくはzshの `typeset -A` で連想配列を作る必要があります。